# scrape fiba stats box score

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i am barely a beginner at python and i would like to have a data set of my favorite local basketball team, that's why i search for a code scraping fiba stats box score , i found one here on stackoverflow and i tried to edit the headers but it just generates an empty csv file, wondering if anyone could help my edit the code below and scrape box score of each team

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

stats_basic = ['NO.', 'PLAYER', 'POS', 'MINS', 'PTS', 'FG', 'FG%', '2P', '2P%', '3P', '3P%', 'FT', 'FT%', 'OFF', 'DEF', 'REB', 'AST', 'TO', 'STL', 'BLK', 'BLKR', 'PF', 'FLS ON', '+/-']
#stats_adv = ['TS%', 'eFG%', '3PAr', 'FTr', 'ORB%', 'DRB%', 'TRB%', 'AST%', 'STL%', 'BLK%', 'TOV%', 'USG%', #'ORtg', 'DRtg', 'BPM']

url_boxscore = "https://fibalivestats.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/u/PBA/2145647/bs.html"
stats1 = []

r = requests.get(url_boxscore)
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
box_scores_content = soup.find_all("div",{"id":"content"})

d = {}
for item in box_scores_content:
    for stat in stats_basic:
        d[stat] = (item.find_all("td",{"data-stat":"fg"})[11].text)
    stats1.append(d)

df=pandas.DataFrame(stats1)
df.to_csv("ginebra.csv")
```

[image: page to scrape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is rendered from external source, so you won't get it in your response and `BeautifulSoup` could not find it.

Take a look into your browsers dev tools and check the xhr tab - you could pull the data and extract needed info from a JSON.

##### Example

Results for first team:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
    requests.get('https://fibalivestats.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/data/2145647/data.json').json()['tm']['1']['pl'].values()
)
```

Comment: thanks got a result but its very long so i tried to save it as a csv but gives me an error `import requests
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json (requests.get('https://fibalivestats.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/data/2145647/data.json').json())
df.to_csv ("ginebra.csv")`

Comment: Cause it is nested - That is why I mentioned you have to *extract needed info* from the JSON, check the edit.

Comment: thanks modified and exported to excel file `import requests
import pandas as pd

# creating the DataFrame
marks_data = pd.DataFrame(requests.get('https://fibalivestats.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/data/2145647/data.json').json()['tm']['2']['pl'].values())
  
# determining the name of the file
file_name = 'ginebra.xlsx'
  
# saving the excel
marks_data.to_excel(file_name)`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your problem, i will not give you the full answer beacuse i really want you to figure it out by yourself since you are a beginner but i will point you to the right direction.

While i was debugging i printed the variable `box_scores_content` and found out it was  empty, than i moved forward and looked in the `BeautifulSoup` documentation for `find_all()` and `find()` method and found really cool stuff which you can dig on your
own in this link: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/.

Your problem is you are not using `find_all()` the right way for your porpuse and also you are not scrapping the right attributes.
Using web tools or `Right click` and then `inspect` on the page i used `CTRL+SHIFT+C` i clicked on the main table and saw how it is defined in the HTML page you gave us, i then saw i need to use `find_all("table")` and use another filters to extract your wanted data.

When web scrapping it is important to know how to use webtools and reading the doc of the libraries you use so you could use them the right way.

Im sure youll figure it out from here :)

Comment: seeing inspect element the headers are inside th tag and the data are inside tr tags

Comment: @mark-kapilyan: Please check your answer twice, main issue is not the use of `find()` / `find_all()` per se and it is scrape, scraping, scraper - scrap/scrapping is something completely different.

Comment: @k1dr0ck they are, but they are under the table component